# How to use RTMP for Video/Audio/Image capture?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, recording

On video/audio/image capture we using net connection like 
`nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/vmspeak");`
Can anyone explain what is this and its use. In new project how to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Adobe [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/go/tryflashmediaserver/) (FMS).

The development edition is free (even for commercial usage) and allows 10 simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 0):

RTMP stands for **Real Time Messaging Protocol**.

Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) was initially a proprietary protocol developed by Macromedia for streaming audio, video and data over the Internet, between a Flash player and a server. Macromedia is now owned by Adobe, which has released an incomplete version of the specification of the protocol for public use.